# What are the best string matching algorithms to search several patterns at once?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

What are the best string matching algorithms which can be used to search multiple patterns within a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For looking for exact match to a number of different strings I favour [the Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), but there are a number of possible contenders, depending on what your patterns are. One starting point to see what is around in practical use would be look at the different variants of grep mentioned [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or pointed to from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What about Rabin Carp and KMP algorithms

Comment: Rabin-Karp is most useful if many/all the target strings are the same length.

Comment: KMP searches for only one pattern at a time. In fact, Aho-Corasick is a lot like a multiple-string version of KMP. Rabin-Carp is indeed most useful when all the strings you are looking for are the same length. If all the patterns are at least of length k, you could search for the first k characters of each pattern and then do a second test to see if all of the pattern was there.